cvSaveImage compilation error on C OpenCV 3.4.20
Hello I try to get into OpenCV for my project. I download the version 3.4.20 that includes the deprecated C headers because my code is on C.
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include "opencv/opencv/include/opencv/cv.h"
 #include "opencv/opencv/include/opencv/highgui.h"
 #include "opencv/opencv/include/opencv/cxcore.h"


void convertToGray(const char* inputImagePath, const char* outputImagePath) {

IplImage* inputImage = cvLoadImage(inputImagePath, 3);
if (!inputImage) {
    printf("Error: Unable to load input image.\n");
    return;
}



if (!cvSaveImage(outputImagePath, inputImage)) {
    printf("Error: Unable to save output image.\n");
}


cvReleaseImage(&inputImage);
}

int main() {
   convertToGray("baboon.jpg", "baboon_grey.jpg");
   return 0;
 }

I just want to copy an input image into another. I use cmake file:
     cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
     project( jpg )
     find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
     add_executable( jpg jpg.c )
     target_link_libraries( jpg ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

When try to compile this error throws:
user@walldm48:~/Desktop/Projet_Diplome$ make
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target jpg
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpg.dir/jpg.c.o
/home/user/Desktop/Projet_Diplome/jpg.c: In function ‘convertToGray’:
/home/user/Desktop/Projet_Diplome/jpg.c:9:28: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cvLoadImage’; did you mean ‘cvCloneImage’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |     IplImage* inputImage = cvLoadImage(inputImagePath, 3);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            cvCloneImage
/home/user/Desktop/Projet_Diplome/jpg.c:9:28: warning: initialization of ‘IplImage *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
/home/user/Desktop/Projet_Diplome/jpg.c:19:10: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘cvSaveImage’; did you mean ‘cvShowImage’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   19 |     if (!cvSaveImage(outputImagePath, inputImage)) {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |          cvShowImage
[100%] Linking C executable jpg
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/jpg.dir/jpg.c.o: in function `convertToGray':
jpg.c:(.text+0x1514): undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
/usr/bin/ld: jpg.c:(.text+0x154c): undefined reference to `cvSaveImage'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/jpg.dir/build.make:112: jpg] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/jpg.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

Could someone explain what I doing wrong ?
Thanks!

the C API is no longer supported. chunks of it may already have been removed from the last 3.4 releases. IIRC the 3.x era was when the C APIs were in the process of being removed. expect everyone to urge you to port this to C++, or write C functions wrapping the C++ API, so that you can use the C++ API in your C program.

I need it on C because i create a Pseudo-random number generator that i will use to crypt images. So I need the opencv only to read the image and then to save the new image. Do you know which version of opencv should i use in order to be compatible with the C code ?

If all you need is to load or save an image, then OpenCV is a massive overkill (even more so, given that the C API has been deprecated for close to a decade now).  I'd be surprised if you couldn't find decent examples on how to use libjpeg or libpng directly.

I will need also to modify pixels of this image. I need to have image for which every pixels should be accessible to modifications.

just pick a different library, or go with C++.
